# Getting the forEach is not a function TypeError

Tags: javascript

I'm currently a student learning JavaScript and I'm trying to create an application that displays data according to user input. The data should be populated using JavaScript, but I keep getting a type error for the forEach on line 10. Please help! This is the code:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  
  const myKey = config.MY_KEY;
  const host = config.HOST;

  const url = 'https://realty-in-us.p.rapidapi.com/locations/v2/auto-complete?input=new%20york&limit=10';

  // Create elements for each city
  function homeList(data) {
    data.forEach(city => {
      const element = document.createElement('ul');
      element.textContent = city;
      document.getElementById('house-list').appendChild('li');
    })
  }
  
  // Fetch data from API
  fetch(url, {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'X-RapidAPI-Key': myKey,
      'X-RapidAPi-Host': host
    }
  })

  .then (res => res.json())
  .then (data => homeList(data))
  .catch(error => console.error(error));
});
```

Comment: Did you try debugging it? Look at the response in the developer tools, sounds like your payload isn't what you expected it to be.

Comment: Please show an example of the data returned. It could be you just need to do data.autocomplete.forEach or similar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The returned response is an object, whose `autocomplete` property is an array of objects. Check the documentation for the API at https://rapidapi.com/apidojo/api/realty-in-us/

You should update the accessing of the data like so:

```js
data.autocomplete.forEach(({ city }) => {
    // ...
});
```

Comment: I'll vote to close as typo-type with a comment. It is not worth answering in my opinion